# Regex to match pattern of at least 7 digits and any amount of special characters in any order

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I need a regex pattern that will match a pattern of at least 7 digits up to 40 and 0 or more of these characters `()+-*#` in any order.

I have this so far: `^[(?=.*\d)(?=.*[+\-*()#\]*)]{7,40}$` but it does not meet all requirements.

Some tests:

`1234 // false needs 7 digits`

`1234563 // true 7 digits and 0 special chars`

`(66)666-666 // true 7 digits and 0 or more special`

`(3)3-33 // false less than 7 digits`

`123456789009876543211234567890098765432112345 // false more than 40 digits`

`()-+*#34345789 // true 7 digits and 0 or more special chars`

`)(*&^%$£@7655432 // false 7 digits but special chars not in list`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't the third condition be false? There are 8 digits.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness - That's part of why I think it's 7-40, not exactly 7.

Comment: I've edited the question for clarification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```js
^[()+*#-]*(?:\d[()+*#-]*){7,40}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JkQlxI/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - [start of string](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)
- `[()+*#-]*` - 0 or more special chars from the [list](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)
- `(?:\d[()+*#-]*){7,40}` - 7 to 40 occurrences of a digit followed with 0 or more special chars from the list
- `$` - [end of string](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).

If you are using it in the `pattern` attribute, you may remove `^` and `$` since they are added automatically by the HTML5 engine.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to match **exactly** seven digits with those various characters ignored, you can do it with this regular expression:

```
^[()+\-*#]*(?:\d[()+\-*#]*){7}$
```

For 7-40, you'd use `{7,40}` instead of `{7}`.

That lets the text start with any of the special chars (or none), then requires at least one digit followed by any of the special cars (or none), seven times.

Example:

```js
function test(str, expect) {
  var result = /^[()+\-*#]*(?:\d[()+\-*#]*){7,40}$/.test(str);
  console.log(str, result, !result == !expect ? "OK" : "ERROR");
}

test("1234", false);
test("1234563", true);
test("(66)666-666", true);
test("(3)3-33", false);
test("123456789009876543211234567890098765432112345", false);
test("()-+*#34345789", true);
test(")(*&^%$£@7655432", false);
```